# Getting an error when trying to import an SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to import an SSIS package that originally came from SQL 2005 to SQL 2016. When importing the dtsx file I keep receiving the error below. I have never dealt with SSIS before so I am kind of stuck at this point.

[image]

Comment: Kindly click on bottom left buttons and display error in detail.

Comment: If the packages are created with the default setting, Encrypt Packages with User key, open packages in the original machine where these are created and change this with Encrypt Package with password and set password for it.